# What should be 'y_train' in Keras LSTM?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, lstm

I refer to the example given at the Keras website [here](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/):

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
import numpy as np

data_dim = 16
timesteps = 8
num_classes = 10

# expected input data shape: (batch_size, timesteps, data_dim)
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True,
           input_shape=(timesteps, data_dim)))  # returns a sequence of vectors of dimension 32
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))  # returns a sequence of vectors of dimension 32
model.add(LSTM(32))  # return a single vector of dimension 32
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Generate dummy training data
x_train = np.random.random((1000, timesteps, data_dim))
y_train = np.random.random((1000, num_classes))

# Generate dummy validation data
x_val = np.random.random((100, timesteps, data_dim))
y_val = np.random.random((100, num_classes))

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=5, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

For a real-world example, what should be y_train and y_val? Should they be the same as x_train and x_val respectively, since they come from the same sequence?

Also, how should I understand data_dim and num_classes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[This](https://machinelearningmastery.com/prepare-univariate-time-series-data-long-short-term-memory-networks/) sort of answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

Since your parameter `return_sequences = True`, your LSTM will be fed numpy arrays of shape `[batch_size, time_steps, input_features]` and perform a "many-to-many" mapping.  `Data_dim` is simply the number of distinct features your model takes as input. Your `y_train` will be of shape `[[1000, 10]]`

The key to understanding the excerpt of code you provided is that setting the parameter `return_sequences = True` enables the LSTM layer to propagate *sequences* of values to upstream layers in the network. Note that the final LSTM layer that precedes the 10-way softmax does not set `return_sequences = True`. This is due to the fact that the Dense layer cannot handle a sequence of inputs - hence, the `time_steps` dimension is collapsed and the Dense layer receives a vector of inputs, which it can process without issue.

Comment: ok... say I have a sequence: 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1, what should be x_train and y_train?